# How to extract two fields from my html using sed

Tags: sed

I want both matches: Campus and Mode but the following code only gets Campus:

```
sed -n 's/.*<th colspan="7">Campus:\(.*\)<br \/> Mode:\(.*\)<\/th><\/tr>.*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your replacement string only includes the `\1` back reference, it's only going to print the first matched group, i.e. the one from `Campus:\(.*\)`. Try changing  your replacement string to `\1 \2` to include both...